# Adding a Variable To Request Object in Django

Tags: django-paypal

How can I add a value to to the request object in django so that is available on redirect. I am trying to sign users up and then redirect them to a paypal link for payment. I want to pass the user id to the paypal submission but can't figure out how to pass the value.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set a variable in the session dict and it worked just fine.